# Not able to get developer license for MarkLogic on Windows 7

Tags: marklogic

MarkLogic 6 is installed on Windows 7 and is running as I can see the home page at localhost and port 8001. However, on the home page if I try to get the license page by providing email id/pwd, it does not do much instead says "Required" for the password. Any idea what could be wrong though it sounds weird.. This software is not installed by me but my admin and now I have the admin access to run this software.

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: It asks for email and _community password_ :)

Answer (score 3):

You need an account on the community website http://developer.marklogic.com for this. Just above the input fields where you enter email and pwd, there should be a phrase like:

```
Please log in or sign up for free!
```

If you don't have an account yet, click the hyperlinked 'sign up'. That will show a similar page, but with more input fields. Enter your details, pick a password, and hit the button on the bottom. That should both create the login for you, and retrieve the license for you.

The Developer license is good for 6 months. The Express license is more limited, but doesn't expire, and allows to be used on one stand-alone production machine for one project. You can always request a renewal for a Developer license, simply by going back to the license page in the Admin interface. That can be found through the Status page of the Host.

HTH!